# How to connect to MongoDB Atlas from Google Compute Engine?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vpc, vpc-peering

I have several MongoDB clusters in Atlas with Network Peering set up and successfully connected all Cloud Run services through VPC accessors. When creating a Compute Engine instance through the web UI, it does not let me choose a VPC so I am wondering how can I connect the VM to Atlas with network peering?

Comment: Compute Engine does not need a VPC connector. The VMs already live in the VPC.

Comment: Simply connect to them from your app

Comment: Choose the correct VPC, and that's all. the serverless VPC connector is for bridging the serverless world managed by Google and your own VPC

Answer (score 0):

To perform VPC peering you requires the next steps:

-Have a paid subscription to Mongo Atlas

-Create a [peering between Mongo Atlas and your project](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/)

-Create a [serverless VPC connector and add it to your App Engine to allow it to reach the private IP on the VPC](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc) and peering attached to the VPC, like your Mongo Atlas DB.